# send the img id to another file with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make this work, I have some images each one of them has this link with its own id.

this is the link: `<a href="#" class="remove_img" data-id="'.$img->g_id.'">x</a>`

this is the script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".remove_img").click(function() {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $this.data('id');
        $.ajax({
           url: 'remove_img.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: { bild : id },
           success: function(data) {

            alert("Gespeichert!");

          }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and I receive the id in the remove_img.php like this: **$_POST['bild']**

in the chrome console I see this error:

> $this is not defined (repetead 2 times)

Comment: share your remove_img.php as well

Answer (score 2):

You want to refer to the jQuery object correctly:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

`$this` is read as a variable that hasn't been declared yet, whereas `$(this)` is the jQuery object wrapper for `this`, or the item that was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

The current way to refer to the current jQuery element is `$(this)` not `$this` (your approach would work if that was a variable with the value of `$(this)` like `var $this = $(this);` which is valid but wouldn't make much sense in your case). So change this line:

```
var id = $this.data('id');
```

To:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

Or (referring to the DOM element directly instead of using jQuery):

```
var id = this.dataset.id;
```